# Using JavaScript in WordPress posts, what is the best practice?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

What is the definitive best practice for using JavaScript in WordPress posts, aside from creating an infinite number of Templates?

Placing it in the HTML tab causes a slew of problems for me, because of the `p` and `br` tags WordPress insists on inserting. Anyone else run into this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you need an infinite amount of templates?  Why not just stick your JavaScript in your template?

Comment: Or just using a plugin to fix up the formatting? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-javascript-in-posts-and-pages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Strip out the white space and returns in your JS and it will work.** That won't give the WP editor anything to add breaks and returns to.

**Or**, throw this in functions.php:

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```

and then bracket your JS in the editor like this:

```
<!-- noformat on -->

<script type="text/javascript">

blah blah blah

</script>

<!-- noformat off -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of hacks that will allow you to do this, but the easiest way is to use a plugin that will allow you to add javascript to individual posts. Google pulled up [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-javascript-in-posts-and-pages/), but I'm sure there are more.

Alternatively, you can write a "shell" javascript file that injects `<script>` tags into your headers based on a page's URL. Let's say you want to add a script file named `testFile` to a page named `testPage` with a URL of `www.mydomain.com/testPage`. Put the following code in a shell file called `shell.js`:

```
    if (location.href === "http://www.mydomain.com/testPage") {
        var testFile = document.createElement("script");
        testFile.setAttribute("src","testFile.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(testFile);
    }
```

You'll need to add a separate script injection code snippet to `shell.js` for each page with custom javascript.

Then add `<script src='shell.js'></script>` to your header template using WordPress' built in editor.

Wordpress has a few [official recommendations](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) as well.